# I am getting "error message: Process exited before completing request"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When I am testing code on the Lambda inline code editor, I always get this error:

```
 "errorMessage": "RequestId: b8efba3e-8940-11e7-a176-e7452208b749 Process exited before completing request"
```

Here is the code (I replaced my code with a sample form amazon just to see if it was only my code):

```
'use strict';
var Alexa = require("aws-sdk");
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
alexa.execute();
};
var handlers = {
   'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('SayHello');
    },
    'HelloWorldIntent': function () {
      this.emit('SayHello');
},
    'SayHello': function () {
        this.emit(':tell', 'Hello World!');
    }
};
```

Comment: This one does not seem to have semicolon at the end of the statement. 
 "HelloWorldIntent': function () {
      this.emit('SayHello')
}"

Comment: added the ; , but still having the same error

Comment: did you check if the value of "this" is correct inside the handler function?

Comment: did a little bit more digging into the log, and it is saying Alexa.handler is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration of Lambda function. By default Handler name should be "index.handler". If it is not exactly same please change it accordingly. If you are uploading the .zip file please sure your main handler function should be in the index.js file. Please refer to the screenshot attached which I marked where to change Handler configuration.

[image]

Comment: The handler name is index.handler. what do you mean by my name handler function should be in the index.js?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a feature of the Lambda output provided in the 'Execution Results'.  Any sort of error resulting in exiting the function code can show up here in abbreviated form as 'Process exited before completing request'.

The best way to view the exact cause of the error is to select the 'logs' link at the top of the Console page, and scroll down to the latest logged messages.